# How can I retrieve a worklight logs from the device written using the Native logging APIs?

Tags: ios, debugging, cordova, logging, ibm-mobilefirst

Can I retrieve log files written to the Native Code worklight log apis in version 6.1.0.0 of Worklight without writing a custom server-side adapter to receive those logs.

This is just for simple tracing and debugging of Native Cordova plugin code.  We have code on iOS that writes to these log methods:

OCLogger.debug()

But these logs never go to the XCode Organizer console.  We found the [documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_uploaded_client_log_data.html?lang=en) on how to send these logs remotely to the Worklight Server, but this is overkill for us, we'd just like to see them in the console on the iOS device for debugging.

Alternatively, we'd like to attach a debugger to this native code with breakpoints to see what's happening.  Either approach would work to help us resolve.

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure the log level for OCLogger is set appropriately.  If it is set to anything less verbose than debug (since you indicated you are calling `OCLogger.debug()`) then you will not see log output to XCode console or anywhere, including server.

Call this early in your application code:

```
[OCLogger setLevel:OCLogger_DEBUG];
```

Comment: thanks, that fixed the issue for us.  Turning up the log level did cause these native logs to go to the XCode Organizer console.